# CONVERT TO VARBINARY AND BACK

Tags: sql-server

I want to change `eHcW080D2C0Yal1XqH/aDg==` to varbinary, it become `0x654863573038304432433059616C315871482F6144673D3D`.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varbinary, 'eHcW080D2C0Yal1XqH/aDg==')
```

But how can I change it back to `eHcW080D2C0Yal1XqH/aDg==`?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it back to a `varchar` type with the same `convert()` function.

```
declare @test1 varbinary(100) = CONVERT(varbinary, 'eHcW080D2C0Yal1XqH/aDg==');

select @test1;
-- output = 0x654863573038304432433059616C315871482F6144673D3D

declare @test2 varchar(100) = CONVERT(varchar(100), @test1);

select @test2;
-- output = eHcW080D2C0Yal1XqH/aDg==
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d0a03af316512d1f7fdddc716f20b56b)

**Side note**: your string looks like a password, converting it to a `varbinary` is not the same as *encrypting* it! As you can see, a simple conversion reveals the password in plain text... Passwords should be *salted* and *hashed* ([background article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4037/storing-passwords-in-a-secure-way-in-a-sql-server-database/)).

Answer (score 0):

just do a convert()

```
SELECT convert(varchar(50), CONVERT(varbinary, 'eHcW080D2C0Yal1XqH/aDg=='))
```